# How to get correct interface orientation in appDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)app?

Tags: iphone, delegates, rotation, orientation, uidevice

I need to get interface orientation in appDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application

```
[application statusBarOrientation];
```

but if the app starts from closed(ie not resumed from background), this always returns portrait, it works when resumed from background.

Also, I tried to use UIDevice orientation along with status bar orientation, but UIDevice orientation may not be the interface orientation.

So is there any way to get interface orientation in app delegate, appDidBecomeActive?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do in the app delegate? The reason I ask is because interface orientation is almost always used regarding views, which is why it's a property on UIViewController... perhaps maybe it can wait until you present the first view controller?

Comment: I need to show a holding view which is identical to the default splash image, but orientation-friendly, that's why I need to know the orientation in app delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is handle this in your splash view controller. You can use a combination interfaceOrientation, shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation, didAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation, etc.

Essentially, create a view controller that you will have as your root view controller. In there, determine the orientation changes in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (it will always be portrait or landscape in viewDidLoad depending on your xib, so don't do it there).  Do your image display with an NSTimer or whatever. After the timer, show your regular app screens.

You can't display the image until you have a view controller anyway, so you must wait until a view controller gives you the interfaceOrientation changes. You should focus on that first view controller, not the app delegate.

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class SplashViewController;
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (retain, nonatomic) SplashViewController *splashController;

-(void)showSplash;
@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "SplashViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize window = _window, splashController = _splashController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self showSplash];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self performSelector:@selector(registerBackground) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
    return YES;
}

-(void)showSplash
{
    SplashViewController *splash = [[SplashViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SplashViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.window addSubview:splash.view];
    self.splashController = splash;
    [splash release];
    //have to add a delay, otherwise it will be called on initial launch.
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(removeSplash:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}

-(void)registerBackground
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(returnFromBackground:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

-(void)returnFromBackground:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self showSplash];
}

-(void)removeSplash:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    [self.splashController.view removeFromSuperview];
    self.splashController = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [_splashController release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Sure, but I am using a holding view and add it to window, instead of a controller, so I have to detect orientation in app delegate

Comment: Why don't you make the holding view part of a view controller?  You should receive the interface orientation calls if you do something like this:  [self.window addSubView:myHoldingController.view];  There also might be an NSNotification call you can use.

Comment: I accepted your answer as it is so far the best answer, but I cannot use view controller because I need to show holding view even when the app is resumed from background, so the home view controller may not be the visible/top view controller.

Comment: When the app is resumed, you can just add the view as a subview to the window.  It doesn't matter if there are other views in a tab bar controller or navigation controller.  If you add it to the window's subview with full dimensions, it will always be on top. You can also setup an NSNotification on some other singleton object for when you get resumed from background. Make sense? Let me know.